# Visual Studio Code Intellisense suggests MS-Specific completions rather than plain Javascript completions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When trying to use

`canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl')`

Visual Studio Code's Intellisense suggests msGetInputContext rather than getContext which is annoying and pointless. Is there something I am supposed to set up in the settings.json file? If not, is this just Visual Studio Code assuming that I am trying to use Typescript? I am rather confused right now

**EDIT**

Below is a screenshot of it. Even at "getCon", intellisense doesn't show "getContext"...

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT 2**

Here are screenshots displaying my extensions

[image: Extensions 1]

[image: Extensions 2]

Answer (score 0):

Check your extensions, if there is a specific extension running which does that.

Comment: It is a fresh install. I haven't installed anything Javascript-related and what I have installed is Haskell ghc-mod and Haskell Syntax Highlighting

Comment: Try installing 'JavaScript and TypeScript IntelliSense'

Comment: Makes no difference. I am still not seeing a "getContext" suggestion

Comment: I had edited the question to include the screenshots on the 6th of december but you haven't made any reply since.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the edit and sorry, I don't know what the problem is then